# Swift 5.7 RegexBuilder convert Array of strings to Regex - ChoiceOf options programatically

Tags: regex, swift5.7, swift-regexbuilder

I would love to take an array of strings

```swift
let array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

and convert it to the regex builder equivalent of:

```swift
Regex {
 ChoiceOf{
  "one"
  "two"
  "three"
  "four"
 }
}
```

or basically the equivelant of:

```swift
/one|two|three|four/
```

so far I have tried:

```swift
let joinedArray = array.joined(separator: "|")
let choicePattern = Regex(joinedArray)
```

I know that using Regex() throws and I need to handle that somehow but even when I do, I don't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is basically the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73915873/5133585). See my answer there - it's kind of a hack IMO. `Regex(joinedArray)` should have worked as well though. Why and how didn't it work exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you, I actually wasn't too far off, I just needed to not be so tired and frustrated, your linked answer was very helpful. By chance do you happen to know anything about the ".mappedOutput" mentioned in the evolution article you mentioned? It does not seem to be available in Xcode.

Comment: Huh, I didn't notice that they also mentioned that in the SE proposal, because I had [a similar idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73815622/5133585). I guess they didn't implement it in the end.